# How to set UILabel to use Arial Narrow (programmatically) just like we do on storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, fonts, uilabel

When we design a UILabel on Storyboards, we can set them as Attributed text, and it's possible to set the Arial Narrow font. But programmatically when we use the code above:

```
   NSRange auxRange = NSMakeRange(0, [myString length]);
   NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [myLabel.attributedText mutableCopy];
   UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Narrow" size:17];
   [attrStr addAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : newFont } range:auxRange];
   myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

We have a pointer to nil for newFont, this happen because the compiler could not find out Arial Narrow as font name.

My question is, why we can set Arial Narrow on Storyboard and we can not do the same on code?
If it's possible, what I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not the compiler that couldn't find the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If after trying @Antonio MG's answer you don't see the font you want, you will have to provide that font yourself.

First, locate the `*.ttf` font file and add it to your App's bundle

Second, add the name of the file to the list of Application provided fonts:

[image]

Then

[image]

**EDIT**: Just for the sake of completeness. Here is how you get the real font name:

1. Open Font Book
2. Locate the font you want
3. Hit the "Info" button
4. Use the name under "PostScript name"

[image]

Finally, you will be able to programmatically use that font in your application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very good @LuisCien, I didn't know how to setup a new ttf font on App's bundle. I did exactly how you show in your answer, dragged /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow.ttf into my project on xcode, setup the Fonts provided, but when I run the apps the compiler still give me a nil pointer on `UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Narrow" size:17];`. What could I have forgot?

Comment: Hi @LuisCien, finally I find out what was wrong. The real font name is the one shown on "PostScript Name" (see Font Book). In my case was ArialNarrow and not Arial Narrow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @GabrielLopes, I just saw your replies. I'm glad I was able to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Print the font list of your phone:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
        }
    }
```

And then check the name of the font you want to add, it has to be there.

Use the name exactly as you see it printed.

Comment: I agree, it could simply just be ArialNarrow or Arial_Narrow.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately there are no Arial Narrow on the list when we print NSLog. This is weird, because on Storyboard we really can choose Arial Narrow.

Comment: The long version of this answer is that [UIFont fontWithName:] requires the font name to be the PostScript name of the font. You can try opening Font Book on the Mac, finding the font, and pressing cmd + i to get the font inspector. That will show you the PostScript name.

Comment: I dont see Arial Narrow on my storyboard :)

Comment: Interesting @Antonio MG, maybe I have this font on Storyboard because some third party software installed on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that the Storyboard editor lets you choose Arial Narrow. It doesn't for me.

In iOS6, Arial Narrow isn't available without using a custom font. You can find a list of the fonts available in iOS6 [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484). As touched on briefly in the [WWDC session on using fonts with TextKit](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/223), iOS7 added support for downloadable fonts. This includes all OS X fonts where [Arial Narrow is available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X).

So, as far as I know, to use Arial Narrow you have a couple of options depending on which version(s) of iOS you're targeting. You can bundle it with your app (this will work on iOS6 and iOS7) or you can write the code to use the built-in support to download and use the font (this will require iOS7).

Comment: Thanks @Andy Wilkinson, I'll look for some example about support to download.

Answer (score 1):

Interface Builder displays a list of fonts that are installed on the OS X system, not the fonts available on iOS.

As a side note, why are you using Arial Narrow? Take a look at HelveticaNeue-Light on iOS.

Comment: I need to design the interface as it was delivered for me. The HelveticaNeue-Light will be my scape in case I can't figure out what is happening. Thanks @Leo Natan.

Comment: The Arial font requires a license, and cannot be packaged in your IPA without one (legally). Also, as a typeface hobbyist, a choice of Arial by a designer is a peculiar choice. A Windows designer perhaps? :)